# Sampling data such that distribution is preserved

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

vsample_data = credit_card.sample(n=100, replace='False')

print(vsample_data)

Here, I was trying to sample 100 data points from a data set but not able to get correct sample data such that it preserves the original distribution of the credit card fraud data-set i.e Class-0( Non- Fraud) and Class-1(Fraud).

Comment: What do mean by not correct? What result did you obtain?

Comment: Look at using sklearn.train_test_split with `stratify=Y` http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn-model-selection-train-test-split

Comment: I was getting random samples of Sometimes Class-0 there only and very few times Class-1 data points present

Comment: Is there any one liner for this so that I get Both classes with same distribution as the original data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stratified samples from Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035187/stratified-samples-from-pandas)

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036118/6018688

Comment: I just have to sample the data such that the sampled data's distribution is same as original data and one more thing the data is highly imbalanced

Answer (score 0):

Increase your sample size (n>>100). The data you are sampling from is itself a random sample. Creating a subset through random selection is itself a random process. If one of the data classes has a low frequency then the problem is that your sample size (100) is too low.

If you change the replace flag to 'True' and do repeated samples, you are doing something called bootstrapping. Assuming the complete data set represents the true population distribution this resampling will give you examples of what kind of measurements you might get for lower values of n (n=100).

The alternative is a stratification strategy as suggested by some above. However, you are not creating random subsets when you do this, and the assumption of distribution is now built into your smaller data sets. Note that you can only achieve this after having looked at the entire data set to determine its distribution. Probably not what you want.

If you are creating a (supervised) training data set from the data you can repeat under-represented data to manipulate the bias.